# Convert a String into a map of indices list in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to write a function that converts a String into a map. The key of the map should be a character, the value of the map is a list of indices the character appears in the String.

For example, the word 'apple' should be converted to:

```
'a': [0]
'p': [1,2]
'l': [3]
'e': [4]
```

The order of the characters does not matter.

My first implementation works:

```
private Map<Character, List<Integer>> generateCharMap(String s) {
    var charMap = new HashMap<Character, List<Integer>>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i ++) {
        var indices = charMap.computeIfAbsent(s.charAt(i), (c) -> new ArrayList<>());
        indices.add(i);
    }
    return charMap;
}
```

I then wanted to use Java stream to do this. The implementation below also works:

```
private Map<Character, List<Integer>> generateCharMap(String s) {
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length())
            .mapToObj(i -> new int[]{(int)s.charAt(i), i})
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> (char)arr[0], Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList())));
}
```

However, I see a big performance reduction with this new stream implementation.

I think it might be because the interim array I created but I could not come up with a better solution.

Can someone please advise if there is a better way to write this using Java stream.

Comment: how are you measuring the performance ?

Comment: This is just one function of my bigger application. The time taken for running my application increased by 20%. No other part of the application is changed.

Comment: have got same result after running it multiple times ? @ZZZ

Comment: *"I see a big performance reduction"* Of course. Don't use streams if you want performance.

Comment: There is no need for the intermediate step, `IntStream.range(0, s.length()).boxed() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s::charAt, Collectors.toList()))`. Besides that, a tiny input string and a low number of executions will always make the loop appear much faster. The more important question is whether this is really the most performance relevant operation of  your application.

Comment: You can omit the `Collectors.toList()` argument in `groupingBy`.  It is implied.